# Detect Click Coordinates Clojure

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have the following ClojureScript code and am trying to detect the coordinates of a a click. So far, I can't even get Javascript alerts to recognize a click, let alone give me the coords.

I know I will have to write a function to have it give me the exact cells being clicked, but as a start, need to know how to get the coordinates of any area clicked on a page.

Thanks!

```
(defn header [color text]
  [:h1
   {:style
    {:color color
     :background-color "blue"}}
   text])

(defn Cell []
  [:div
    {:style
     {:width "40px"
      :height "40px"
      :float "right"
      :margin-bottom "1px"
      :margin-right "1px"
      :background-color "grey"
      :border "1px" "solid" "white"}}])

(defn home-page []
  [:div
   [header "red" "Minesweeper"]
   [:div
    {:style
     {:width "440px"
      :height "440px"}}
    (repeat 100 [Cell])]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an `:onClick` key at the same map indentation level as the `:style`. Its value should be a function, which will get an event `e`. Then:

```
(let [coords (.getClientPosition e)
      coords' {:x (aget coords "x")
               :y (aget coords "y")}])
```

Here's an example of a hashmap that has an `:onClick` event and its function:

```
{ :href "#"
  :onClick (fn [e]
               (.preventDefault e)
               (swap! counter inc))}
```

The only thing that matters in the above is getting the `e` and using it. That was taken from the [flappybird example program](https://github.com/bhauman/flappy-bird-demo), which is how I got started.

Comment: Thank you Chris but I am getting an error that says Use of undeclared Var cljs-minesweeper.core/getClientPosition.

Comment: Well, I tried switching it to (js/getClientPosition) and that error went away but now I am getting "Use of undeclared Var cljs-minesweeper.core/e"

Comment: No such luck. I'm very new to Clojure so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong in setting :onClick's value to a function.

Comment: Okay - I'll find an :onClick (my reference was Om, so might be different). Usually people use React, which means they use either Reagent or Om.

Comment: It's probably just the typo in `(.getClientPostion e)` that confuses Jessie.

Comment: Sorry about that Jessie - the code I copied had this: `[goog.style :refer [getClientPosition getPageOffset]]`, hence the dot was absent. (thanks Erik :))

Comment: No worries! So is it supposed to be...
    `{:onClick (fn [e]
               (let [coords (.getClientPosition e)
                     coords' {:x (aget coords "x")
                              :y (aget coords "y")}]))`

Comment: That looks right. I amended the answer by putting the dot in. Just do `(println 'coords)` to see them. You'll need `(enable-console-print!)` to use `println`.